# ng-route [HOW TO]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I try to follow official angular documentation for ng-route how ever I'm lost.
So I hope you can advise me.

I try to add routing for my existing simple site with 2 controllers. One for login and one for display data.

So I add something like this to main.js:

```
var historyApp = angular.module('historyApp', ['ngRoute', 'LoginCtrl', 'HistoryCtrl']);

historyApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        }).
        when('/history', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/history.html',
            controller: 'HistoryCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });
    }]);
```

Where Loginctrl and HistoryCtrl are really simple controllers like:

```
historyApp.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $scope.getToken = function(){
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '../../api/v1/Oauth.php',
            data: { login : $scope.username, password : $scope.password }
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    };

});
```

So config is set and controllers and templates exists (for sure), 
I also added ng-route.js to login.html and history.html

But when I open `localhost/myProject/#/login` and also `localhost/myProject#/login` I'm not redirect to login page it basicly just display me my root directory.

How this parths are working?
Is it from root dir or from somewhere else?
Or what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
added screen:
[image]

Comment: Does it throw any error ?? Check your browser console and let us know what it says

Comment: have you tried     localhost/myProject/#/login?

Comment: As @jax says, try  localhost/myProject/#/login. your rooter seems well writed for me. what is the error, and what is your html page.

Comment: @jax, just test it, it display directorys of my project

Comment: do you have a view for login at templates/login.html?

Comment: I'm not sure if I undersatnd this question correctly jax, but yes I see folder inside which is folder templates, inside which is this folder

Comment: @Andurit can you show us the full URL that you are using .

Comment: can't be problem in that templates are always full HTML files from <html> to </html> so I'm it's not just <body> ?

Comment: Is your url alright? can you post a screenshot for clarity

Comment: @Jax I just added screen, in web folder there are folder for js ( where main.js is located) and also folder for templates

Comment: can you be more specific please?  I expect I am wrong if program is not working correctly but I can't see where.

Comment: do you have a index file, which bootstraps the angular app through the ng-app? and did you assigned ng-view to a container in the index file?

Comment: where should be this file located? does it need some default name like index.html ?

Comment: I have made an example a while back, you can find it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6cwmkf?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you @skubski :), it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you have the `ng-view` directive in your page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
    ...
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>

<div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```